# Open Slider Link in New Window

Tags: php, wordpress

In a custom Wordpress blog site designed by our marketing agency, I need to have the home page slider images open their URL links in a new window:

Here's the link variable code from slider.php:

```
<?php foreach ( $sliders as $slider ) : ?>
            <li>
                <?php if ( ! empty($slider['slider_url']) ) : ?><a href="<?php echo $slider['slider_url']; ?>"><?php endif; ?>
                    <img src="<?php echo $slider['slider_image']['url']; ?>" />
                <?php if ( ! empty($slider['slider_url']) ) : ?></a><?php endif; ?>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach;?>
```

Comment: add target="_blank" in the appropriate place.

Answer (score 0):

If your link is opening in the same window properly then you need to add target="blank". Make  the following changes and enjoy.

replace this `<a href="<?php echo $slider['slider_url']; ?>">` with `<a href="<?php echo $slider['slider_url']; ?>" target="_blank">`

Answer (score 0):

Why are you double checking if not empty slider_url ? 
Also, you should put the 'li' tag inside the if statement, because if the data are empty you don't want an empty 'li' tag to exist inside the slider.

Anyway, this should do what you asked for

```
<?php foreach ( $sliders as $slider ) : ?>
    <?php if ( ! empty($slider['slider_url']) ): ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo $slider['slider_url']; ?>" target="_blank">
                <img src="<?php echo $slider['slider_image']['url']; ?>" /> 
            </a>
        </li>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach;?>
```